# How to generate a confirmation popup in Coldfusion 8

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, popup, coldfusion-8

I'm working on a CFC in Coldfusion 8 and I need to setup a confirmation popup before a person deletes a record. Here is my base piece of code I'm working with:

```
<!---Initiated when user clicks "Delete Association"--->
<!---User should be prompted by a popup to confirm intent to delete--->
<!--if user confirms delete, click event in popup triggers function below--->
<cffunction name="DeleteEmployeeAssignment" access="remote" 
       description="deletes selected employee from selected report assignment" 
       returntype="void">
    <cfquery name="qryDeleteEmployeeAssignment" datasource="Corp_Dev" dbname="Corp_Dev_DB">
        DELETE FROM [Corp_Services_Dev].[dbo].[AssignedReports]
        WHERE employeeID ='11283' AND assignedReport = '1'
    </cfquery>
    <!---User is given a success message on deletion--->
</cffunction>
```

Because this is before CF9 I can't use the CFwindow tag. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use something like jQuery UI - [Dialog with modal confirmation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Comment: Are you passing in some sort of record ID as an `argument` in the real code? Also, do not forget to VAR scope all function local variables - including query names.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try `return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')` as an `onClick` event on whatever is calling the method.  You showed us the method that you are calling, but this would be on whatever is calling the method.  So, if "Delete Association" is a button or a link, you should be able to use the `onClick` event there.  Not fancy, but it should get the job done.  Many other ways to skin that cat using the JavaScript library of your choice.